# How to change woocommerce product image upload path

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress multisite with one main and four child website. i have done plugin for share woocommerce product to childsite. now child site can add or update mainsite product from  child site. but when displaying in front end the media path is wrong. i want use all child site product image path to same path. how it possible ?

Comment: how are the multisite structure, with subdomain or subdirectory? when you say the media path is wrong, how it's displaying it and how do you want to be displayed.

Comment: subdomain. actually my task is to list main site's woocommerce product it child site and update from child

Comment: I just got confused, you said you CAN create/edit/delete products that are on  the main site from the child sites, and your problem is that (what I understood) the images are NOT displaying correctly, probably the url is `mainsite.com/images/product1.jpg` but when you are on the child site the url change to `child1.mainsite.com/images/product1.jpg` im just making assumptions. In order to help I need you to give more info about it. Thanks.

Comment: hi thanks for the response 
I just change the global variable $wpdb values to change current site table to main site like wp_4_posts to wp_posts   when url has 'post_type=product' wpdb value will change;  when i am editing main product from child i passed 'post_type' in post.php's URL because of this set featured images are not loading if i remove post_type=product from posts.php, set featured will work but main posts not loading

Answer (score 3):

In woocommerce plugin and in file class-wc-admin-post-types.php
woocomerce override the WordPress upload filter through the filter 'upload_dir'

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', array( $this, 'upload_dir' ) );
public function upload_dir( $pathdata ) {
    // Change upload dir for downloadable files
    if ( isset( $_POST['type'] ) && 'downloadable_product' == $_POST['type'] ) {
        if ( empty( $pathdata['subdir'] ) ) {
            $pathdata['path']   = $pathdata['path'] . '/woocommerce_uploads';
            $pathdata['url']    = $pathdata['url']. '/woocommerce_uploads';
            $pathdata['subdir'] = '/woocommerce_uploads';
        } else {
            $new_subdir = '/woocommerce_uploads' . $pathdata['subdir'];

            $pathdata['path']   = str_replace( $pathdata['subdir'], $new_subdir, $pathdata['path'] );
            $pathdata['url']    = str_replace( $pathdata['subdir'], $new_subdir, $pathdata['url'] );
            $pathdata['subdir'] = str_replace( $pathdata['subdir'], $new_subdir, $pathdata['subdir'] );
        }
    }

    return $pathdata;
}
```

so if you want to override it, you can create filter to this 'upload_dir' with higher priorites.

Answer (score 3):

I would call this a try and error thing, I had done something similar but it takes some time customizing as your desired.

So here it's what I believe could solve your main problem:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', '_my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);
function _my_pre_get_posts( $wp ) {
  global $typenow, $blog_id;

  if ( 'product' == $typenow && $blog_id != 1) {
    switch_to_blog(1);
  }
}
```

if the `$blog_id` is not the main site (*reads* ID = 1) you should switch to blog ID 1, all this is happening before all post are pulled from the database.

**product** is the current post_type being queried, if you want this to work with orders as well you probably will check for `'shop_order'`.

To know which post_type is being queried you should check the url, Ex: `/edit.php?post_type=shop_order`.

This probably would bring some issues such as the title of the blog in the adminbar is the one from the main site, and it's missing that at some point it needs to restore to the main site back, but at least this should do the trick.

check this Solution and Let me know how end up